# What are the '.#' links for?

Tags: spacemacs, files, saving, symbolic-links

When an Emacs buffer is modified, a broken link is created.
The link's name is a concatenation of '.#' followed by the file's name.
For example:

```
$ ls .#spacemacs_ref.org -l
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 wolfv wolfv 44 Aug 18 01:11 .#spacemacs_ref.org -> wolfv@localhost.localdomain.17997:1502966690
```

The '.#' link goes away when the file is manually saved, but not when auto-saved.
Auto-save happens in 30 seconds and the mode-line's '*' changes to '-'.
If I manually save the file after auto-save occurs, the mini-buffer says "(No changes need to be saved)".  Which is true, but the '.#' link remains.

In my .spacemacs configuration file sets auto-save to original file:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/init ()
...
(setq-default
...
 dotspacemacs-auto-save-file-location 'original
```

What is the purpose of the '.#' links?

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbolic links of the form “.#*” are not auto-save files, their purpose is to prevent the simultaneous editing of the same file. See [Interlocking](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html#Interlocking) and [File Locks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html) in the Emacs Manual.